# How to make MCU with 256kB memory?

Tags: microcontroller, memory

(Reposting)

I have 48MHz clocked ADC that outputs data continuously.  My MCU will take the data at some interrupts and need to send it to iPhone.   The amount of data collected are abt 178k Bytes.  I guess i need 256kB memory.  MCU does not seem to have that big data memory.
What can be the best way in terms of cost and circuit simplicity??

Comment: Most of the STM32F407 parts have 192KB ram, there may well be ARM cortex parts from others with 256K.  You could also consider an external ram or possible fifo.  With a processor you probably want to use DMA, even then 48MHz point more towards a dedicated ram/fifo.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with your title, which is about making a processor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the part.  As expected, mcu with big sram like STM32F407 is kind of pricey.  Is it more affordable to go with external ram or FIFO in terms of cost and complexity?

Comment: at <$20 hardly pricey for a one-off compared to developing a board to put it on, and if you are targeting quantity you should have a better idea of what you really need.  Depending on your throughput requirement a discrete fifo may be more appropriate.

Comment: What's with the "(Reposting)" statement(?) - was the question re-posted, if so why?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can either switch to a part with enough internal RAM or add external RAM. The STM32 has options that would work for both solutions. The STM32F42x line can be purchased with the full 256 kB of RAM you are asking for. I believe Freescale may have options in the Kinetis family that also meet this requirement. All the STM32's in appropriately large packages also have an external memory interface on which you could hang an SRAM chip.

It is worth looking to see if your microcontroller has hidden memory elsewhere that you may be able to use. For example, some microcontrollers may have small dedicated memory banks for Ethernet and USB that could be used for storage if the peripheral is not needed for its intended purpose.

You could also evaluate data compression algorithms (lossy and lossless) that might reduce your memory requirement, or rearchitecting your system so that you can send the data to the iPhone more frequently.